# How to test .css file for syntax errors?

Tags: css

I (all too often) fat-finger a mistake into a .css file.  (Missing or extra **}** is the most common)

I'm using Expression Web and it only highlights the spot of the error. In a 500 line CSS that's really easy to miss.

Is there a good resource, tool, etc. for testing CSS for syntax errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use CSSLint for checking CSS errors

[CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also find CSS errors using **Firebug**.

In the *Console* tab in Firebug, click the drop-down and tick the `Show CSS Errors` option.